# Dúvida com JQuery - Pegar valor da class e aplicar como background

Tags: jquery, formulário, checkbox

preciso de um help!!

Estou fazendo um formulário e cada checkbox vai ter uma imagem, porém eu não queria fazer manual pelo css cada check, queria um script que já fizesse automático.

Eu sei fazer isso com a função click(), mas precisava que já puxasse quando carregasse a página.

Gostaria de pegar o valor da classe do Checkbox e aplicar como background da label. Mas queria uma função que funcionasse pra todos.

Será que alguém pode me dar uma luz??
Thanks

```css
.estilos li{ float: left; list-style: none; width: 23%; margin-right: 2%;}
 .estilos li:last-child{ margin-right: 0 }

input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
cursor: pointer;
}
 
input[type=checkbox] + label
{

background: #ccc;
padding: 100px 0 10px;
width: 100%;
display:inline-block; 
cursor: pointer;
text-align: right;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label img{
 position: relative;
 right: 20px;
 opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
padding: 100px 0 10px;
width: 100%;
display:inline-block;  
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label img{
 opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<ul class="estilos">
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='Teste' id="thing" class="01" />
    <label for="thing">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" width="36">
    </label> 
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='Teste' class="02" id="thing2" />
    <label for="thing2">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" width="36">
    </label>       
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='Teste' class="01" id="thing3" />
    <label for="thing3">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" width="36">
    </label>       
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='Teste' class="02" id="thing4" />
    <label for="thing4">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" width="36">
    </label>       
  </li> 
  <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: você quer identificar o checkbox que estiver checado e atribuir uma classe ao label dele no load da pagina? é isso?

Comment: @Dirce Não consegui entender o que você quer fazer, ao adicionar o atributo checked no checkbox ele já mostra o ícone.

Comment: Então gente, eu quero que cada campo tenha uma imagem.
Atualmente ta cinza, mas não queria colocar uma classe pra cada um com a imagem, sabe?

Queria fazer td em JQuery

Comment: Editei o codigo abaixo, agora esta pegando as imagens no loading da pagina.

Comment: conseguiu fazer? a solucao funcionou?

Answer (score 1):

Pronto,veja se é isto mesmo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name="thing"]').each(function(idx,key){
    var dataimg = $(key).attr('data-img');
    $(key).next().css('background','url(https://dmhxz00kguanp.cloudfront.net/fotos/'+dataimg+')');
  
  });

});
```

```css
.estilos li{ float: left; list-style: none; width: 23%; margin-right: 2%;}
 .estilos li:last-child{ margin-right: 0 }

input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
cursor: pointer;
}
 
input[type=checkbox] + label
{

background: #ccc;
padding: 100px 0 10px;
width: 100%;
display:inline-block; 
cursor: pointer;
text-align: right;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label img{
 position: relative;
 right: 20px;
 opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
padding: 100px 0 10px;
width: 100%;
display:inline-block;  
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label img{
 opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="estilos">
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='Teste' id="thing" data-img="79314/media_kit-berco-chapeuzinho-vermelho-almofadas-de-brincar-176688.webp" class="01" />
    <label for="thing">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" width="36">
    </label> 
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='Teste' class="02" id="thing2" data-img="81467/media_kit-berco-amiguinhos-181596.webp"/>
    <label for="thing2">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" width="36">
    </label>       
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='Teste' class="01" id="thing3" data-img="83379/media_quarto-de-bebe-ursinha-bebe-186658.webp"/>
    <label for="thing3">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" width="36">
    </label>       
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='Teste' class="02" id="thing4" data-img="83379/media_quarto-de-bebe-ursinha-bebe-186658.webp"/>
    <label for="thing4">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" width="36">
    </label>       
  </li> 
  <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Poderia excluir a outra resposta então. :)